# Qt Progress Bar: change colour

Tags: qt, progress-bar

Is there a way to change the colour of a progress bar with Qt 5.7?

For example, on Windows 7 progress bars become red when there is an error, I'd like to do something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Widgets, then you have stylesheets available. However you won't be able to keep the original Windows 7 look. Here is an [example for the QProgressBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qprogressbar).

For QtQuick Progress component, you have the [`style` property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-progressbar.html#style-prop) available. Here is the [documentation page with the example](http://documentation%20page%20with%20the%20example).